# Remove users storage folder with firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

When a user deletes their account, I want to remove their storage files along with their data.

I am able to do a multi path delete for the RTDB, how can I do this but also remove files from storage too?

I have tried chaining on a `.then` but it makes everything fail...

ex...

```
.then(() => {
  const bucket = gcs.bucket(functions.config().firebase.storageBucket);
  const path = `categories/${uid}`;
  return bucket.file(path).delete();
})
```

I wish it was faster to test your functions without always deploying because it has taken soooo much time to try making this work...

Here is my working code:

```
exports.removeUserFromDatabase = functions.auth.user()
  .onDelete(function(user, context) {
    var uid = user.uid;

    const deleteUserData = {};
    deleteUserData[`users/${uid}`] = null;
    deleteUserData[`feed/${uid}`] = null;
    deleteUserData[`friends/${uid}`] = null;
    deleteUserData[`profileThumbs/${uid}`] = null;
    deleteUserData[`hasUnreadMsg/${uid}`] = null;
    deleteUserData[`userChatRooms/${uid}`] = null;
    deleteUserData[`userLikedPosts/${uid}`] = null;
    deleteUserData[`userLikedStrains/${uid}`] = null;

    return admin.database().ref('/friends').orderByChild(`${uid}/uid`).equalTo(uid)
    .once("value").then((friendsSnapshot) => {
      friendsSnapshot.forEach((friendSnapshot) => {
      deleteUserData[`/friends/${friendSnapshot.key}/${uid}`] = null;
    });
    return admin.database().ref().update(deleteUserData)
    })
    .then(() => {
      // const bucket = gcs.bucket(functions.config().firebase.storageBucket);
      const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
      const path = `categories/${uid}`;
      return bucket.file(path).delete();
    })
  });
```

I feel like it's because I am not dealing with the promise correctly, I just don't know where this is going wrong.

My code snippet currently works until i chain the `.then()`

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is not returning anything from the top-level code, meaning it may get terminated at any point while it's writing to the database.

You'll want to `return admin.database()...` and *then* chain the additional `then()` after it.

Comment: Thank you, I did some looking around and came to the realization that you cannot delete a folder with all its items. What would you recommend if i wanted to delete every item in the folder (user's images) at once? Perhaps a cloud function that triggers on each post deletion (use the img id for a reference) or would that be considered, "expensive".

Comment: If you want to delete everything in a "folder" (there are actually no folders), then you need to need to use the Cloud Storage list API to find all those files with a common prefix ("folder"), iterate them, and delete them individually.